# Math, 2 equations 2 unknowns, and matlab, plot

Tags: matlab, math

i am trying to solve these 2 equations with 2 unknowns.
i want to find the angle of a1(alpha1), a2(alpha2) in radians.
however when i solve it in maple i get 0.112 for a2 and 0.089 for a1.
but some other guys used matlab and they get something different with plot and 2 angles..
can someone tell me if i am right or he is?
MY equations:
equation 1: 4/(2*pi)*(cos(2*a1)+cos(2*a2))=0
equation 2: 4/(10*pi)*(cos(10*a1)+cos(10*a2))=0

his matlab:

```
j=0;
for i=0:pi/100:1
j=j+1;
a2(j)=i;
a1_1(j)=acos(-cos(2*i))/2;
a1_2(j)=acos(-cos(10*i))/10;
end

plot(a2,a1_1,'-k',a2,a1_2,'-b','LineWidth',1.4);
```

I wanna plot like him..but i am not sure his Equations a1_1 is correct?
by the way the main equation it came from:
bn =  4/(n*pi)*(cos(n*a1)+cos(n*a2))=0
bn = 0 and n is 2th and 10th harmonics to be eliminated

Comment: `dphi=pi/1000; a2 = 0:dphi:1; a1_1 = acos(-cos(7*a2))/7; a1_2 = acos(-cos(13*a2))/13;` is a more idiomatic variant for matlab. Use array evaluation to avoid loops wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
cos(A)+cos(B) = 0
```

happens for

```
A + B = pi + 2*k*pi  or A - B = pi + 2*k*pi
```

Both of the two original equations could resolve the the same of the two variants or to different variants. Resolving to the same equation, say the first, will produce

```
7*(a1+a2) = pi + 2*k7*pi  and  13*(a1+a2) = pi + 2*k13*pi
```

which can only hold if

```
0 = 6*pi + 2*(13*k7-7*k13)  <=>  3 = 7*k13-13*k7
```

which implies `a1+a2 = pi + 2*m*pi`. .

In the case of different to different variant, one obtains (modula sign variations of `a1, a2`)

```
7*(a1+a2) = pi + 2*k7*pi  and  13*(a1-a2) = pi + 2*k13*pi
```

and thus

```
a1 = (pi/7+pi/13)/2 + k7*pi/7 + k13*pi/13
a2 = (pi/7-pi/13)/2 + k7*pi/7 - k13*pi/13
```

and all possible sign variations, since cosine is an even function. However, simultaneous sign variations are also covered by variations of `k7` and `k13`. Thus you obtain additionally (up to) `2*7*13=182` solutions to your problem.